# Disable the closing of ngx-smart-modal on outside click

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using the ngx-smart-modal and it is working fine but the problem is that I want to disable it closing when a click is initiate outside the modal or in the body.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ngxSmartModalService.getModal('classicModalregister').open()">Register</button>
<ngx-smart-modal #popupRegister [identifier]="'classicModalregister'" customClass="medium-modal">
<h1>Register Here !</h1>
<p>dfdfd</p>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

Answer (score 3):

Following the  documentation
we can set parameter/option on `ngx-smart-modal`  tag as the `dismissable`, the parameter that allow to close or not at outside click.

So we got `[dismissable] = "false"`

The fix:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ngxSmartModalService.getModal('classicModalregister').open()">Register</button> <ngx-smart-modal #popupRegister [identifier]="'classicModalregister'" customClass="medium-modal" [dismissable] = "false"> <h1>Register Here !</h1> <p>dfdfd</p> </ngx-smart-modal>
```

Remember: Always read the documentation!

Documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-modal